# What should I make as my first JQuery application?

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I want to get better at JQuery, but I don't know what type of application I should make to test my skills. What would you suggest that would not be too hard so I would get frustrated as a beginner.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2006-01-29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the tutorials on the jquery site, they are very good

[tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

Comment: Came in here to suggest the same thing.  +1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but may actually be helpful:
Why jQuery? What other JavaScript frameworks did you look at? Do you think, you have a good understanding of JavaScript at all?

While jQuery is not only popular, but also very good (two things that often exclude each other), I don't think it is a good way to start learning JavaScript.
The point of frameworks as jQuery is to prevent JavaScript developers of doing the same, stupid, dull, quirky JS-coding over and over again. However, I think before starting to use jQuery, you should first have a shot at that very stupid, dull and quirky work, to understand JavaScript and frameworks like jQuery.

Then, when you have made a project with classic JavaScript and HTML, try simplyfying and enhancing it using jQuery. jQuery has it's place, but as [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) elegantly put it, it is clearly overused, even in places where it's more complicated: http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery

Now if you really do not want to fight the intricacies of DOM manipulation, I'd rather suggest pure JavaScript frameworks such as [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/), which unlike jQuery doesn't simplify DOM manipulation, but rather promotes a clear, component based, object oriented and high level approach to creating JavaScript RIAs.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: We should give the OP the benefit of the doubt; and yet, the overwhelming popularity of jQuery has apparently blurred this distinction for beginners.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/2657095#2657095

Answer (score 0):

It is VERY common to write a "tips" plugin - hence why there are many :)  You have lots of examples to compare to, and can add "enhancements" to make it fancy to expand your skill set.